# Angular2 polymorphic nested components break when in separate files

Tags: typescript, nested, polymorphism, components, angular

I get the error: "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component" when I put polymorphic components in separate files, but no error when they're all in the same file. **I've studied all the SO questions on this error to no avail**, but since I've got a working and non-working scenario, hopefully there are some ng2/typescript gurus out there that can help me sort this out:

I've boiled the issue down to a toy scenario where I have composite celestial objects (Galaxies, Solar Systems, Stars). Any celestial object can contain any other celestial object. I know -- some people might say a star can't contain a galaxy, but they've probably never watched Dr. Who. :-)

My main component sets up descriptors and creates the top-level component, which in this case is a galaxy:

```html
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CelestialObject} from './CelestialObject';


@Component({
  selector: 'preview',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="descriptor"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class MainComponent {
  private descriptor;

  constructor() {
    this.descriptor = {
      type: 'galaxy',
      children: [
        { type: 'solarSystem', children: [{type: 'star', children: []}] },
        { type: 'star', children: []}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

- **Working**: All components in the same file (undesirable from code organization standpoint)

CelestialObjects.ts:

```html
import {Component, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'celestial-object',
  template: `
    <span #loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere></span>
  `
})

export class CelestialObject implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() descriptor: any;

  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) { /* */
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let objectType: any = null;

    switch (this.descriptor.type) {
      case 'solarSystem':
        objectType = SolarSystem;
        break;
      case 'galaxy':
        objectType = Galaxy;
        break;
      case 'star':
        objectType = Star;
        break;
    }

    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(objectType, this.elementRef, 'loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere').then((comp) => {
      comp.instance.descriptor = this.descriptor;
    });
  }
}

//======================================
// Galaxy
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'galaxy',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Galaxy</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class Galaxy {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}

//======================================
// SolarSystem
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'solar-system',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Solar system</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class SolarSystem {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}

//======================================
// Star
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'star',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Star</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class Star {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}
```

- **Not working**: Put galaxy component into a separate file.

CelestialObjectsMinusGalaxy.ts:

```html
import {Component, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {Galaxy} from './Galaxy';

@Component({
  selector: 'celestial-object',
  template: `
    <span #loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere></span>
  `
})

export class CelestialObject implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() descriptor: any;

  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) { /* */
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let objectType: any = null;

    switch (this.descriptor.type) {
      case 'solarSystem':
        objectType = SolarSystem;
        break;
      case 'galaxy':
        objectType = Galaxy;
        break;
      case 'star':
        objectType = Star;
        break;
    }

    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(objectType, this.elementRef, 'loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere').then((comp) => {
      comp.instance.descriptor = this.descriptor;
    });
  }
}

//======================================
// SolarSystem
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'solar-system',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Solar system</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class SolarSystem {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}

//======================================
// Star
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'star',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Star</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class Star {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}
```

And Galaxy.ts. Same code as before, just split out into a separate file and importing CelestialObject:

```html
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {CelestialObject} from './CelestialObject';

//======================================
// Galaxy
//======================================
@Component({
  selector: 'galaxy',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <p>Galaxy</p>
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="obj" *ngFor="#obj of descriptor.children"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class Galaxy {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
}
```

And now I get the error. I realize that this winds up being a circular reference, but isn't there a way to keep these components in their own files without getting the "Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component" error?

Any help greatly appreciated. This one's been a bear to unravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Galaxy imports CelestialObject and CelestialObject imports Galaxy. Sasxa suggested getting rid of the switch statement, thus freeing the CelestialObject from its dependency on Galaxy.

This led to the solution of populating the descriptor with actual type, rather than a string representing the type:

```html
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {CelestialObject} from './CelestialObject';
import {Galaxy} from './Galaxy';
import {SolarSystem} from './SolarSystem';
import {Star} from './Star';


@Component({
  selector: 'preview',
  directives: [CelestialObject],
  template: `
    <celestial-object [descriptor]="descriptor"></celestial-object>
  `
})

export class MainComponent {
  private descriptor;

  constructor() {
    this.descriptor = {
      type: Galaxy,
      children: [
        { type: SolarSystem, children: [{type: Star, children: []}] },
        { type: Star, children: []}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Then the CelestialObject becomes the following, with no dependencies on the specific celestial objects:

```html
import {Component, Input, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'celestial-object',
  template: `
    <span #loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere></span>
  `
})

export class CelestialObject implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() descriptor: any;

  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) { /* */ }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(descriptor.type, this.elementRef, 'loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere').then((comp) => {
      comp.instance.descriptor = this.descriptor;
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks to Sasxa for providing the critical puzzle piece.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to remove type switch and replace it with event emitter 
 in your `CelestialObject`:

```
export class CelestialObject implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() descriptor: any;

  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, 
              private emitter: SharedEmitterService,
              private elementRef: ElementRef) { /* */
    this.emitter.subscribe(objectType => load(objectType));
  }

  load(objectType) {
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(objectType, this.elementRef, 'loadSpecificCelestialObjectHere').then((comp) => {
      comp.instance.descriptor = this.descriptor;
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your other classes you can initiate the load:

```
export class Galaxy {
  @Input() descriptor: any;
  constructor(private emitter: SharedEmitterService) { /* */ }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.emitter.emit(Galaxy);
  }
}
```